# Modeling computational dependencies between property values in an Ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

I have an Ontology with an entity called :Entity1 (right now its modelled as a class but we can make it an individual, if needed. It has properties called :hasValue1 and :hasValue2. I want to capture the fact that the value for :hasValue2 should always be 0.35 times the value for :hasValue1.

So, if I have the triple ":Entity1 :hasValue1 10", I want to enforce the "fact" that ":Entity1 :hasValue2 3.5".

What is the best way to do this in a semantic model?

Comment: In a semantic model, SWRL rules are indeed most appropriate. For the real world, I suggest that you enable write access to the dataset via a REST microservice and use ShEx/SHACL shapes (or even custom logic in the code, esp. if that check requires many lookups, which you can optimise with hash tables) before inserting the data into the triplestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require to use [SWRL rules](https://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/)